# finding the basis of the kernel for some matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of all $2 \times 2$ real matrices. The basis of $V$ consists of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 &0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, I have a map $T : V \rightarrow V$ whose matrix form is $$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I'm currently trying to figure out the **basis** for $ker(T)$. So through the row reductions, I get that $ker(T) = \big{\{}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}t_1 + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}t_2 \text{ for } t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R} \big{\}}$.

Thus, my guess was that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ 0\\1 \end{pmatrix} $ should be the basis of $ker(T)$. However, I also know that $ker(T)$ is a subspace of $V$, which is a vector space consisting of $2 \times 2$ real matrices. So shouldn't the basis of the kernel be $2 \times 2$ matrices instead of $4 \times 1$? What am I confusing here?

My question also applies for the range. I get that the first two columns of the  matrix are the basis for the range, but again, they are $4 \times 1$ matrices. Shouldn't they be $2 \times 2$ since the range is also a subspace of $V$?

Comment: The question seems poorly framed. $T$ does not multiply with $2 \times 2$ matrices in the usual way, so how exactly is $T$ mapping anything from $V$ into anything, much less $V$ itself?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer So $T : V \rightarrow V$ is defined by $T(A) = AB - BA$ for some $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$. Does that help? Should I include that in my question?

Comment: What are $e_{11}$, $e_{12}$, $e_{21}$, and $e_{22}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry for the confusion. I edited my post.

Comment: The $4$-tuples are [coordinate vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector). So the fact that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is one of the vectors you found means that $-1$ times the second matrix in your basis + the third matrix in your basis is in the kernel.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Oh wow, I didn't know about them! Thank you.

Comment: The question is poorly framed. What is the formula for T? If you state it clearly, then you will understand how to calculate the basis for kernel of T using the standard procedure. You have calculated 4-D vectors in R^4 as the basis entries of kernel of T which does not make sense if T maps V to V, where V consists of $2 \times 2$ matrices.